# Replacing the name using hashmap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

```
My java class

    public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {

    BeanClass beanclass1 = new BeanClass();
    BeanClass beanclass2 = new BeanClass();
    BeanClass beanclass3 = new BeanClass();
    BeanClass beanclass4 = new BeanClass();
    BeanClass beanclass5 = new BeanClass();

    beanclass1.setId(1);
    beanclass1.setName("Peter");
    beanclass1.setAddress("WI");

    beanclass2.setId(2);
    beanclass2.setName("Jack");
    beanclass2.setAddress("Aus");

    beanclass3.setId(3);
    beanclass3.setName("Vivek");
    beanclass3.setAddress("canada");

    beanclass4.setId(4);
    beanclass4.setName("Deva");
    beanclass4.setAddress("Calf");

    beanclass5.setId(5);
    beanclass5.setName("Arun");
    beanclass5.setAddress("NY");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String,BeanClass> hm1 = new HashMap<>();
    hm1.put("First", beanclass1);
    hm1.put("Second", beanclass2);
    hm1.put("Third", beanclass3);
    hm1.put("Fourth", beanclass4);
    hm1.put("Fifth", beanclass5);
    String st = gson.toJson(hm1);
    System.out.println(st);
    HashMap hm = gson.fromJson(st, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(hm);
  //  HashMap hm = gson.fromJson(st, HashMap.class);
   // System.out.println(hm); here to change beanclass3 name..
    }}
    output:{"Second":{"id":2,"name":"Jack","address":"Aus"},"Third": {"id":3,"name":"Vivek","address":"Canada"},"First":{"id":1,"name":"peter","address":"WI"},"Fourth":{"id":4,"name":"Deva","address":"calf"},"Fifth":{"id":5,"name":"Arun","address":"NY"}}
```

> {Second={id=2.0, name=Jack, address=Orrisa}, Third={id=3.0,
>   name=Vivek, address=Kerala}, First={id=1.0, name=Ram,
>   address=Chennai}, Fourth={id=4.0, name=Deva, address=WestBengal},
>   Fifth={id=5.0, name=Arun, address=Mumbai}}

Here i need to change third beanclass3 name to change...how to do?

Comment: There is no information to your problem. Just a piece of code and one line won't help much. Tell us what you want to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to update the name of `beanclass3` stored in the `HashMap` :

```
((BeanClass)(hm.get("Third"))).setName("newName");
```

Comment: This type of exception occur....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.cindrel.Json.BeanClass
 at .Json.Mainclass.main(Mainclass.java:47)
Java Result: 1

Comment: ..  i will try this code...correct or wrong?      HashMap hm2= gson.fromJson(st, HashMap.class);
       ((BeanClass)(hm2.get("Third"))).setName("john");
        System.out.println(hm2);

Comment: i got error..Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast

Comment: @KRISHJIRAO cannot be cast to what?